# Is there a django idiom to store app-related variables in the DB?

Tags: python, django, variables, persistence, idioms

I'm quite new to django, and moved to it from Drupal.

In Drupal is possible to define module-level variables (read "application" for django) which are stored in the DB and use one of Drupal's "core tables". The idiom would be something like:

```
variable_set('mymodule_variablename', $value);
variable_get('mymodule_variablename', $default_value);
variable_del('mymodule_variablename');
```

**The idea is that it wouldn't make sense to have each module (app) to instantiate a whole "module table" to just store one value, so the core provides a common one to be shared across modules.**

To the best of my newbie understanding of django, django lack such a functionality, but - since it is a common pattern - I thought to turn to SO community to **check if there is a typical/standard/idiomatic way that django devs use to solve this problem**.

(BTW: the value is not a constant that I could put in a settings file. It's a value that should be refreshed daily, and should be read at each request).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are apps to achieve this, but I'd like to recommend [django-modeldict](https://github.com/disqus/django-modeldict) from disqus, as its brief

> ModelDict is a very efficient way to store things like settings in
>   your database. The entire model is transformed into a dictionary
>   (lazily) as well as stored in your cache. It's invalidated only when
>   it needs to be (both in process and based on CACHE_BACKEND).

Comment: I've looking for something similar to this for a while - this looks like a good implementation. Three cheers for Disqus.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to fit the bill perfectly. :)

Comment: ModelDict project is now discounted. You might want to consider using DurableDict from the same developers instead: 
 https://github.com/disqus/durabledict/

Answer (score 2):

Data that is not static is stored in a model. If you need to share data or functions between apps I have seen the convention of making a shared app, something like 'common'. This would house shared models, or utility functions.

In the django projects I have seen the data is usually specific. The data you are storing should be in a model that is representative of that data, I would rather have an explicit model/object representing my data then a generic object that houses vastly different data.

If you are only defining 1 or two variables which are changed daily, perhaps just a key/value store like memcached would work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Another +1 for ModelDict.  Another potential, similar solution is Django Constance:

https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance

It's meant to store app config parameters in the database and has the advantage that it exposes a nice backend to edit them for administrators (with the right permissions), handles default values and also has caching etc.

**EDIT:**

In case it's not clear from the documentation (which it isn't), you can set settings the same the 'Pythonic way.'  I.e. to set a setting to a value, you do

from constance import config

config.variable_name = value